# Mobo and SLI support

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I'm not an expert of SLI technology, but I know that the mobo must support the SLI and there is also the BRIDGE SLI to connect the GPUs.
I have two questions:

1. is the Bridge SLI mandatory?
2. if the mobo doesn't support SLI but has at least two PCIe x16 slots, can I put 
   a second card and connect both by the SLI Bridge? Or the SLI support for the mobo 
   is mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copied from TomsHardware.com](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/nvidia-sli-faq,4079.html#p2)

1. A motherboard with at least two free PCIe x16 slots, operating in at least in x8 mode (Nvidia does not support SLI on x4 links). Pretty much all LGA 2011, LGA 2011-v3 and LGA 1150/1151 motherboards satisfy this requirement.
2. Two (or more) identical Nvidia-based cards that support SLI, or a dual-GPU card like the GeForce GTX 690 or Titan Z. Generally, different cards won't do the trick.
3. A suitable power supply. Increasing the number of GPUs in a system rapidly increases its power requirements. Take that into account when you choose your PSU.
4. An SLI bridge. This is generally provided by your motherboard's manufacturer as a bundled accessory.
5. The latest Nvidia drivers. If you're reading this article, we're pretty sure that you know that you can grab these from Nvidia's website.

You CPU also must support that many lanes. (Most "modern" CPUs support at least 16 which is just enough for SLI with two cards)

Comment: I think these statement are colliding a bit with what Nvidia says at:
https://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/technology/sli/system-requirements
"SLI motherboard is required for all SLI configurations. "
Am I wrong?
So, what's the purpose in making sli and non-sli mobo?

Comment: Any board that has at least 2 PCI-express x16 slots and a minimum speed of 8x on both slots will run SLI.
Which is what Nvidia means when they talk about a SLI Motherboard. You might want to check https://www.nvidia.com/object/sli-ready-motherboards.html too, if you want officialy tested ones